# if PendSV have lowest priority why it is set to 15 in RTOS

Tags: rtos

```c
/* The lowest interrupt priority that can be used in a call to a "set priority"
function. */
#define configLIBRARY_LOWEST_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY   15
 
/* The highest interrupt priority that can be used by any interrupt service
routine that makes calls to interrupt safe FreeRTOS API functions.  DO NOT CALL
INTERRUPT SAFE FREERTOS API FUNCTIONS FROM ANY INTERRUPT THAT HAS A HIGHER
PRIORITY THAN THIS! (higher priorities are lower numeric values. */
#define configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY 5
```

I was expecting that if the PendSV have the lowest priority after int main() then it should be nearest value to 0

Comment: What processor architecture are you referring to?  The fragment suggests that the RTOS is FreeRTOS.  This is specific to FreeRTOS and not a general RTOS question, you should tag it as such and probably mention it in the questions.  Also the fragment does not mention PendSV so how have you determined that this applies to PendSV?

Comment: Note the edit to the code mark-up.  In future use the correct mark-up (_markdown_ syntax) or use the composer toolbar buttons and check the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this refers to FreeRTOS on Cortex-M, then you have I think confused FreeRTOS task priorities where zero is the lowest priority and Cortex-M NVIC priorities where zero is the *higest priority*

Note the warning at https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/08/28/arm-cortex-m-interrupts-and-freertos-part-3/

[image]

The entire article is probably instructive and will answer any questions you have on FreeRTOS interrupts on Cortex-M